# How can I change the value of a row with indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've scraped the crypto.com website to get the current prices of crypto coins in DataFrame form, it worked perfectly with pandas, but the 'Prices' values are mixed.

here's the output:

```
                     Name                           Price 24H CHANGE
0             BBitcoinBTC      16.678,36$16.678,36+0,32%     +0,32%
1            EEthereumETH        $1.230,40$1.230,40+0,52%     +0,52%
2             UTetherUSDT                $1,02$1,02-0,01%     -0,01%
3                 BBNBBNB            $315,46$315,46-0,64%     -0,64%
4           UUSD CoinUSDC                $1,00$1,00+0,00%     +0,00%
5        BBinance USDBUSD                $1,00$1,00+0,00%     +0,00%
6                 XXRPXRP            $0,4067$0,4067-0,13%     -0,13%
7           DDogecoinDOGE           $0,1052$0,1052+13,73%    +13,73%
8             ACardanoADA            $0,3232$0,3232+0,98%     +0,98%
9           MPolygonMATIC            $0,8727$0,8727+1,20%     +1,20%
10           DPolkadotDOT                $5,48$5,48+0,79%     +0,79%
```

I created a regex to filter the mixed date:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\$.*)(\$)')
for value in df['Price']:
    value = pattern.search(value)
    print(value.group(1))
```

output:

```
$16.684,53
$1.230,25
$1,02
$315,56
$1,00
$1,00
$0,4078
$0,105
$0,3236
$0,8733
```

but I couldn't find a way to change the values. Which is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. What does it mean to **change the values** ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: hi, ive tried you regex expression but i got this
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='$1.230,40$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='$1,02$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='$315,46$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='$1,00$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='$1,00$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='$0,4067$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='$0,1052$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='$0,3232$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='$0,8727$'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='$5,48$'>

Comment: @Clegane i want that the prices in the first table, ex: 16.678,36$16.678,36+0,32% be the prices like in the second output: $16.684,53

Comment: @Clegane i couldnt find a way to change the values on the dataframe :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if youre regex expression is good, this would work

```
df['Price']= df['Price'].apply(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group(1))
```

Comment: it worked perfectly! Thank a lot. I'm a begginner and i didnt knew this .apply() function

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
df['price_v2']=df['Price'].apply(lambda x: '$' + x.split('$')[1])

'''
0     $16.678,36+0,32%
1            $1.230,40
2                $1,02
3              $315,46
4                $1,00
5                $1,00
6              $0,4067
7              $0,1052
8              $0,3232
9              $0,8727
10               $5,48
Name: price, dtype: object
```

Also, BTC looks different from others. Is this a typo you made or is this the response from the api ? If there are parities that look like BTC, we can add an if else block to the code:

```
df['price']=df['Price'].apply(lambda x: '$' + x.split('$')[1] if x.startswith('$') else '$' + x.split('$')[0])

'''
0     $16.678,36
1      $1.230,40
2          $1,02
3        $315,46
4          $1,00
5          $1,00
6        $0,4067
7        $0,1052
8        $0,3232
9        $0,8727
10         $5,48

'''
```

Detail:

```
string = '$1,02$1,02-0,01%'
values = string.split('$') # output -- > ['', '1,02', '1,02-0,01%']
final_value = values[1] # we need only price. Thats why i choose the second element and apply this to all dataframe.
```

Comment: Your resolution worked as well ! thanks for answering me :)